# Display the content in the ListView and the text is cut off

Tags: wpf, xaml

I display the content in the ListView and the text is cut off.
It is impossible to move the horizontal scroll bar further, even though this text is longer.
Do you have any idea how to solve this?
Thank you very much.

```
   <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Margin="20">
        <ListView x:Name="ProductDetails"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ProductDetailsCollection}"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  />
    </Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem... it's working fine form me. Did you use some listview item template? Is ProductDetailsCollection a list of string? I need more code

Comment: This collection is a list of string.
Yes, I was using listview item template and rather cannot modify this template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this problem you could create a new `Style` in your window like this:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
     <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
     <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
</Style>
```

It should adjust the text and prevent the cut off.

If you already have a custom style for your `ListView` or your `ListViewItem` check you aren't overriding properties like the one I posted

Comment: I have already custom style and cannot add anothe stle to <Windows.Resources>

Comment: @PiotrX why do you mean with `cannot add anothe stle to <Windows.Resources> ` ?